# Pattern for react components that require specific contained components

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-component

What's the idiomatic React way to write a component that nests specific child components? I know how to write a component that simply wraps `props.children`, like this example from React's own docs:

```
function FancyBorder(props) {
  return (
    <div className={'FancyBorder FancyBorder-' + props.color}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

But what if I wanted to create a pair of components that can be used like this:

```
<TabSet>
  <Tab name="Mammals">
     content for <b>warm blooded</b> creatures here
  </Tab>
  <Tab name="Fish">
     content for <b>cold blooded</b> creatures here
  </Tab>
</TabSet>
```

Here's my initial implementation of `TabSet` (using [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/)), simplified to remove styling, selected-tab management, and other stuff not related to this question.

```
import React, {Fragment, Component} from 'react';
import { TabContent, TabPane, Nav, NavItem, NavLink } from 'reactstrap';

export default class TabSet extends Component {

  render(props) { 
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Nav tabs>
          {props.children.map((tab,i) => 
            <NavItem key={i}>
              <NavLink>
                { tab.name }
              </NavLink>
            </NavItem>
          )}
        </Nav>
        <TabContent>
          {props.children.map((tab,i) => 
            <TabPane key={i} tabId={i}>
              { tab.children }
            </TabPane>
          )}
        </TabContent>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }

}
```

Where I'm stuck is how to implement the `Tab` component. Logically, it's part of the `TabSet` component-- it should never stand alone. And its implementation should be painfully simple because it doesn't actually do anything-- it's just a container for a `name` attribute and child elements.

So, here's a few questions:

- Should I create a separate JS file for the `Tab` component, or is it so simple that I should just export it as part of the implementation of the `TabSet` component? If the latter, how?
- In classes that use `TabSet`, will I need two `import` statements, or is there a way I can import both `TabSet` and `Tab` with one `import`, kinda like `import React, {Fragment} from 'react'` works ?  If the latter, then how would the export statement look in TabSet.js?

Apologies for what's probably an obvious question-- I'm a newbie to both React and ES6.

Comment: If the code of `Tab` component, I think you shouldn't take it to separate file. And to use with one `import` statement, just `export const Tab ...` in the same file with `TabSet` which is exported by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the component is only used in context of another component it is logical to put them both in same module and many libraries do that. The way to achieve this is use multiple `export` statements without `default`. You are allowed to use one `export default` and as many `export` statements as you need. Like this

```
export default class TabSet 
...
export class Tab
```

and to import

```
import TabSet, {Tab} from './Tab'
```

The general syntax being

```
import defaultExport, { namedExport1, namedExport2  } from "module"
```

The syntax might seem a bit confusing [here is the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Answer (score 0):

Where you are using `export default class ...` you can actually export your own object here. With that in mind, you are able to something like:

```
const TabSet = props => (
  <Your Tabset markup here>
)

const Tab = props => (
  <Your Tab markup here>
)

export {
  Tabset,
  Tab
}
```

Doing it like this will allow you to import both components in the one line by doing:

```
import { Tabset, Tab } from 'wherever'
```

---

Now while this is one way to do it, and although you think `Tab` is quite simple, I still believe they belong in their own files. So just create the two class files for `Tabset` and `Tab`, but then make a third file called `tabs.js` or something. It should contain the link to both, like:

```
import Tabset from './tabset'
import Tab from './tab'

export {
  Tabset,
  Tab
}
```

This way you have designated files for each component, and you can import them as a single import.

---

Also for bonus, if you use the `PropTypes` ability of react, you can restrict the children of the `Tabset` to actually be your Tabs. [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) is the overview, but as an example you can do something like:

```
// untested
static propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.instanceOf(Tab))
}
```

You will have to import the `Tab` component into the set component to do this.